# IllegalAccessError: tried to access field com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessage.memoizedSize while using KMS decrypt

Tags: scala, google-cloud-kms

Am facing  the following error while trying to decrpyt a cipher string using Google KSM SDK version `1.40.0`.

Code used:

```
try (KeyManagementServiceClient keyManagementServiceClient = KeyManagementServiceClient.create()) {
   CryptoKeyName name = CryptoKeyName.of("[PROJECT]", "[LOCATION]", "[KEY_RING]", "[CRYPTO_KEY]");
   ByteString ciphertext = ByteString.copyFromUtf8("");
    DecryptResponse response = keyManagementServiceClient.decrypt(name.toString(), ciphertext);
   }
```

Error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access field com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessage.memoizedSize from class com.google.cloud.kms.v1.DecryptRequest
            at com.google.cloud.kms.v1.DecryptRequest.getSerializedSize(DecryptRequest.java:472)
            at io.grpc.protobuf.lite.ProtoInputStream.available(ProtoInputStream.java:108)
            at io.grpc.internal.MessageFramer.getKnownLength(MessageFramer.java:205)
            at io.grpc.internal.MessageFramer.writePayload(MessageFramer.java:137)
            at io.grpc.internal.AbstractStream.writeMessage(AbstractStream.java:65)
            at io.grpc.internal.ForwardingClientStream.writeMessage(ForwardingClientStream.java:37)
            at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.sendMessageInternal(ClientCallImpl.java:544)
            at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.sendMessage(ClientCallImpl.java:528)
            at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCall.sendMessage(ForwardingClientCall.java:37)
            at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.asyncUnaryRequestCall(ClientCalls.java:308)
            at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.futureUnaryCall(ClientCalls.java:218)
            at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcDirectCallable.futureCall(GrpcDirectCallable.java:58)
            at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcUnaryRequestParamCallable.futureCall(GrpcUnaryRequestParamCallable.java:65)
            at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcExceptionCallable.futureCall(GrpcExceptionCallable.java:64)
            at com.google.api.gax.rpc.AttemptCallable.call(AttemptCallable.java:86)
            at com.google.api.gax.rpc.RetryingCallable.futureCall(RetryingCallable.java:63)
            at com.google.api.gax.rpc.RetryingCallable.futureCall(RetryingCallable.java:41)
            at com.google.api.gax.tracing.TracedUnaryCallable.futureCall(TracedUnaryCallable.java:75)
            at com.google.api.gax.rpc.UnaryCallable$1.futureCall(UnaryCallable.java:126)
            at com.google.api.gax.rpc.UnaryCallable.futureCall(UnaryCallable.java:87)
            ... 27 more
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you have different versions of protobuf in the classpath. Use some shade plugins to rename the proto class in the final build jar.

**Example sbt (assembly)** ::: https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly#shading

```
assemblyShadeRules in assembly := Seq(
  ShadeRule.rename("com.google.protobuf.**" -> "shade.protobuf.@1").inAll,
)
```